# devise undefined method `users_url' for RegistrationsController

Tags: devise

Rails 3.2.12 + Devise 2.2.3

A NoMethodError occurred in registrations#create:

undefined method `users_url' for #<RegistrationsController:0x007fd04f04b330>
  actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:129:in`polymorphic_url'

the app works fine on rails 3.2.8

Comment: found anything? experiencing the same issue on devise 2.1.2 and rails 3.2.8, 3.2.9 and 3.2.13

Comment: I have the same error. No solution?

Comment: Can you please post the full stack trace....

Comment: Please post your routes.rb file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266532/public-activity-rails-undefined-method-user-path/15285186#15285186

Comment: This solve? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971357/devise-undefined-method-users-url-for-deviseregistrationscontroller0x0000

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, it looks a problem inside Devise (still present in master).
The only solution I found was to go back to Devise 2.1.2 (I knew it was working because I used it in another project).

So to fix this problem you can put

```
gem 'devise', '2.1.2'
```

in your Gemfile and then re-install it with

```
rails generate devise:install
```

Hope it helps you while Devise's team fixes it