# Devise undefined method `users_url' for #<Devise::RegistrationsController:0x00000003b299b0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get this error with devise registration:

```
undefined method `users_url' for #<Devise::RegistrationsController:0x00000003b299b0>
```

With Omniauth facebook, login, everything works fine.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy

  after_save :myprofile

  def myprofile
    if self.profile
    else
      Profile.create(user_id: self.id, user_name: self.name)
    end
  end
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

What could be the solution to get this working with devise registration?

Important: It **works with omniauth facebook**, but it **doesn't work with devise** registration.

Edit: i get this error with Profile.create! method:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `users_url' for #<Devise::RegistrationsController:0x00000005946e20>:
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:129:in `polymorphic_url'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:150:in `url_for'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb:105:in `_compute_redirect_to_location'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb:74:in `redirect_to'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/flash.rb:25:in `redirect_to'
```

Edit_2:
**Github repo:**
https://github.com/gwuix2/anabol

Github issue:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2457

Comment: The child model (profile) will need a user_id to point back to.  If you try to make the child first before the user saves and gets an autogenerated ID you'll have trouble.  Why not save the user then immediately create the profile?

Comment: I thought about this too. But as I remember it didn't work,I mean the after_save method. Edit: Edited the question, just tested with after_save, doesn't work.

Comment: I think there needs to be something with devise, because with omniauth facebook it works.

Comment: Try `Profile.create!(user_id: self.id, user_name: self.name)`. It will raise an exception if there is a problem with creating the profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved:

in profile.rb:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :slug
```

caused the problem, because for Profile.user_name the following in user.rb:

```
after_save :myprofile

def myprofile
  Profile.create!(user_id: self.id, user_name: self.name)
end
```

Problem solved by adding an uniqueness validation to User.name, which then passes as unique to the Profile, which then creates a unique :slug.

user.rb:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name
```

Answer (score 0):

The profile you're creating with `Profile.create(user_id: self.id, user_name: self.name)` isn't associated with any User. In order to build a `has_one` dependency, use the `build_resource` method on `self` in an `after_create` callback:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy

    after_create :myprofile

    def myprofile
        profile = Profile.create!(user_id: self.id, user_name: self.name) # `.create!` will throw an error if this fails, so it's good for debugging
        self.profile = profile
    end
end
```

Comment: Sorry I don't get it, I get `undefined method build_myprofile'`

Comment: With build_profile, it doesn't work, doesn't create the profile for the user

Comment: Updated. Give the revised snippet a try.

Comment: Didn't work. I really think its somehting with devise. Because with facebook it works.

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? Or is the profile simply not being created?

Comment: I just get nil class error in the view, because there is no profile, also checked it with console, it doesn't get created.
However with omniauth facebook login, it gets created.

Comment: Agh. Okay, giving it one last shot... check out the revision that invokes the `create!` method and associates the newly created `Profile` object with your `User` object.

Comment: I don't really get it, but if I link here the github repo could you give it a shot?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31357/discussion-between-zeantsoi-and-railsbeginner)